# AddDbContext conditional by Request-Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, configuration

I´ve got a configuration-class which holds database connection-strings per mandant. But only with the requests parameters the mandant will be clear. So I want to inject the right DbContext contitional by mandant.

So far I´ve the following problem:

```
    public class MessageController : IMessageController
{
    private readonly IMessageParser _parser;
    private readonly ILogger _log;
    private readonly IMessageProcessor _receiver;

    public MessageController(IMessageParser parser, IMessageProcessor receiver, ILogger log)
    {
        _parser = parser;
        _log = log;
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public async Task<Response> MessageReceivedEvent(Request request)
    {

        if (!_parser.TryParseMessage(request.SomeInlineData, out var mandant))
        {
            _log.LogError("The given Message could not be parsed");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The given Message could not be parsed");
        }

        // what to do with the mandant?

        _receive.Received(request);

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

The receiver may has the following logic:

```
public class MessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor 
{

    // this database should be injected dependend on the current mandant
    private readonly DbContext _database;
    public MessageProcessor(DbContext database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }
    public void Received(Request request) 
    {
        // Do fancy stuff

        _database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now here the `ConfigureServices`:

```
    services.AddDbContext<DbContextX>((provider, options) => options.UseSqlite($"Data 
             Source={Path.GetFullPath("How to get the right mandant connection string?")}"))
            .Configure<MandantConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MandantConfiguration)))
```

Here the configuration class:

```
public class MandantConnection : IMandantConnection
{
    public string DatabaseConnection { get; set; }
}

public class MandantConfiguration : IMandantConfiguration
{
    public Dictionary<Mandant, MandantConnection> Mandants { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

The DbContext is injected as Scoped, so I think it should be possible to change the Connection-String per Scope but I don´t know how.

Comment: You have a controller and the data in the response needs to be loaded into the database.  the dbContext class contains mapping information that matches the tables/column in the database. The connection string to the database should always be the same.  The response may contain different type of data and needs to go into different tables in the database.  The MessageProcessor() must take the Response (not the dbContext) and write to the dbContext.

Comment: We have two different mandants where both have there own Database which they are working on. Therefor I need to change the connection string dependend on the request. I´ve heard its possible to give a scope some informations but how?

Comment: What type database?  Is it same server?  Is struct of two databases the same? With dbContext there is a mapping file that maps the c# classes to the database.  Switching connection string means changing mapping as well.  It may make sense to have two dlls (two class projects), one for each database.  The dbContext is usually loaded when application starts.  Switch dbContext after app is started is possible but will take time to load dbContext every time it changes.   There are also links that are created between database and c# classes that would need to get refreshed.

Comment: Yes the tables and columns are the same per mandant and the databases are on the same database-server but in different databases. As the Database is injected as scoped I thinke per request it takes time anyway

Comment: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/multitenancy-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: The you can use same connection string and just add a "USE DATABASE" to query change database. May be use Raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the HttpContext within the request.

So far here my solution for the given Problem:

```
public class MessageController : IMessageController
{
    private readonly IMessageParser _parser;
    private readonly ILogger _log;
    private readonly IMessageProcessor _receiver;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public MessageController(IMessageParser parser, IMessageProcessor receiver, ILogger log, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _parser = parser;
        _log = log;
        _receiver = receiver;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public async Task<Response> MessageReceivedEvent(Request request)
    {

        if (!_parser.TryParseMessage(request.SomeInlineData, out var mandant))
        {
            _log.LogError("The given Message could not be parsed");
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The given Message could not be parsed");
        }

        // ---> Thats to do
        _accessor.HttpContext.Items[nameof(Mandant)] = mandant;

        _receive.Received(request);

        return new Response();
    }
}
```

Then I´ve implemented a MandantService, which injects the Accessor also:

```
public class MandantenService : IMandantenService
{
    public IMandantConnection CurrentConfiguration { get; set; }

    private readonly MandantConfiguration _configuration;

    public MandantenService(IOptions<MandantConfiguration> options, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _configuration = options.Value;

        CurrentConfiguration = _configuration.Mandants[Enum.Parse<Mandant>(accessor.HttpContext.Items[nameof(Mandant)].ToString())];
    }
}
```

Then I can use this service within the DbContext:

```
        public VdvKaDbContext(DbContextOptions<VdvKaDbContext> options, IMandantenService mandantenService)
            : base(options)
        {
            _mandantenService = mandantenService;
            ...
        }
```

And configure the Sqlite Database in the OnConfigure-Method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={Path.GetFullPath(_mandantenService.CurrentConfiguration.DatabaseConnection)}");
}
```

And boom every call of scoped database will be the specific mandant database:

```
    using var scope = _provider.CreateScope();

    return scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DbContext>();
```